# Degree of freedom of prediction interval

Tags: linear-algebra

We are interested in examining the yield of tomato plants that have been grown with certain types of fertiliser. A study is conducted and the following data obtained:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snwII.png)

We want to Find a 95% prediction interval for the yield of a tomato plant grown on fertiliser 1.

I not sure shall I take 1 or 5 for the degree of freedom of the prediction interval. Can someone explain for me please? Thanks very much!

Comment: I have changed your tag "linear algebra" into "statistics"...

Comment: yeah thanks, the subject name is linear statistical models, and so I made the mistake.